# Split C string by non-alpha characters

Tags: c, string, substring

I'm working on a program which takes in a file for input, reads the file, then counts the number of times each unique word appears. I need to split each word along any non-alpha character. For example, `aren't` would become `aren` and `t`, two separate words. How would I go about doing this? I'm currently doing this:

```
char* test = strtok(buffer, "   1234567890.,':;/\"?!@#$%^&*()'\0'\n");
while (test != NULL){
    BST->root = addToBST(test, BST->root);
    test = strtok(NULL, "   1234567890.,':;/\"?!@#$%^&*()'\0'\n");
    }
```

However, this seems pretty inefficient and I'm sure there's a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: In general there is nothing wrong with what you are doing. If you want to make it "pretty", then you can declare `const char *delim = "   1234567890.,':;/\"?!@#$%^&*()'\0'\n";` and use `delim` where you have the whole string -- but that is just for your enjoyment (and readability for others) -- the compiler doesn't care... As for your second question, you can eliminate `"'"` from `delim` and use `strchr (token, '\'')` to check if the token contains `'` and handle those words separately.

Comment: You also don't need `'\0'` as part of your delimiter string. (and you don't need multiple spaces at the beginning -- multiple sequential delimiters in `buffer` will be treated as a single delimiter)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin *You also don't need `'\0'` as part of your delimiter string*  "Don't need" isn't strong enough - putting a `'\0'` **ends** the delimiter string - any character after that won't be considered as a delimiter.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Oh right you are -- that's why 4-eyes are always better than 2, 2 may be partially asleep....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — I suspect that the 'multiple blanks' are actually a blank and a tab.  The tab would be better written as `\t`, though.  (Now that's 8 eyes instead of 2 or 4 — I wear glasses!)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use alternating calls to [`strspn` and `strcspn`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strspn.3.html) to find the lengths of each word and of each interword sequence. Once you know the start and length of a substring, you can create a dynamically-allocated copy with [`strndup`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strndup.3.html) or you can compare with a stored word of known length with [`strncmp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strncmp.3.html).

That's not necessarily the fastest solution. As you note, using a long string of delimiters (or non-delimiters) requires a lot of character testing or the construction of a boolean vector, which is a lot of overhead for string pieces which are likely to be a few characters. Still, it's reasonably fast and developer time is important, too.

I listed all of the above in part to show that modern C has to a large extent surpassed the limitations of the original string library design and its dependence on NUL-termination, if you're prepared to venture beyond the K&R string functions. In practice, however, I'd probably write this in [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/),  which efficiently handles most of the buffer management and does the scan with a precomputed trie (or state machine), which is generally faster than anything you're going to throw together without a lot of effort. YMMV. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps take advantage of the fact that ASCII letters are mostly contiguous in decimal number sequence (a-z : 65-90, A-Z : 97-122) to reduce the number of comparisons, by building your own version of strtok based on this general concept:

```
void tokenizer(char* target) {
    int i = 0;
    char test = target[0];
    while (test != '\0') {
        if ((test >= 65 && test <= 90) || (test >= 97 && test <= 122))
            printf("%c", test);
        else {
            printf("\n");
        }
        ++i;
        test = target[i];
    }
}
```

Then perhaps collect each word into a buffer, run it through a hash function to get a unique identifier, plug that into a binary search tree as a struct (ordered by hash value, word name, and count) to count the duplicates of unique words?

Comment: Well your loop could be reduced to: `while (*target != '\0') putchar(isalpha(*target++) ? '\n' : target[-1]);` by including `stdio.h` and `ctype.h` but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @clearlight After puzzling with that code for some time I realized it was reversed, I think this is how it goes, slight change in syntax: ```while (*target != '\0') {putchar(isalpha(*target++) ? *(target - 1) : '\n');}```  but thanks for making me review the ternary operator! (and c-string pointers, and ```putchar```).

Answer (score 0):

Using the `strspn()` and `strcspn()` functions is as good as you can do with the standard C library, but it isn't very hard to write code that out-performs those if you're repeatedly searching for the same set of characters, which is a common pattern.

Create a function `set_span()` that sets an array of 256 bytes to all bytes zero, then sets those characters listed in a string (that would be the search argument for `strspn()` or `strcspn()`) to 1.

Then create functions `str_span()` and `str_cspan()` that take one of the initialized arrays and the string to be searched.  These can very quickly check whether each character in the string is counted or not.  Note that the names `str_span()` and `str_cspan()` are not reserved by the C11 standard ([§7.31.13](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.31.13)).

This code is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `strspan-1.03.tgz` in the [packages](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/packages) sub-directory.  The library files are `strspan.h` and `strspan.c`; the other files provide test support code.  There isn't code to put `strspan.o` into a library.  (The package assumes you use GCC; it is not hard to revise the `makefile` for other compilers if you don't use GCC.)

I ran some tests on a small file (`great.panjandrum`) and on a large file (`bible-be.txt` — the Holy Bible in Basic English).  The timing results when processing each file 3 times was:

```
$ test2.strspan great.panjandrum great.panjandrum great.panjandrum
# NB: The tests for str_span and strspn are comparable
#     The tests for strlen and strchr are not comparable
strlen   0.000046 (487) great.panjandrum
strlen   0.000031 (487) great.panjandrum
strlen   0.000030 (487) great.panjandrum
strchr   0.000036 (487) great.panjandrum
strchr   0.000030 (487) great.panjandrum
strchr   0.000030 (487) great.panjandrum
str_span 0.000035 (487) great.panjandrum
str_span 0.000032 (487) great.panjandrum
str_span 0.000031 (487) great.panjandrum
strspn   0.000061 (487) great.panjandrum
strspn   0.000052 (487) great.panjandrum
strspn   0.000053 (487) great.panjandrum
$ test.strspan2 bible-be.txt bible-be.txt bible-be.txt
# NB: The tests for str_span and strspn are comparable
#     The tests for strlen and strchr are not comparable
strlen   0.187297 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strlen   0.186324 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strlen   0.187616 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strchr   0.182676 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strchr   0.185405 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strchr   0.184813 (4467663) bible-be.txt
str_span 0.195715 (4467663) bible-be.txt
str_span 0.199516 (4467663) bible-be.txt
str_span 0.194588 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strspn   0.347890 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strspn   0.346028 (4467663) bible-be.txt
strspn   0.347305 (4467663) bible-be.txt
$
```

The times for the `strlen()` and `strchr()` test basically measure the time to read and scan the files — `strlen()` is looking for a null byte; `strchr()` is looking for a newline.  Running them first means that the I/O system has the files in memory, etc.

The times for `str_span()` and `strspn()` show that `str_span()` is much quicker than `strspan()`.  It's measurable even on a file with less than 0.5 KiB of data; it is quite noticeable in a file with about 4.5 MiB of data.  JFTR, the testing was done on a 2017 MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with (home compiled) GCC 9.3.0 and Xcode 11.3.1.

Both of these tests alternate using the positive match followed by the negative match.

Note that the setup functions, `set_span()` and `set_ranges()`, both initially zero the array argument (it's actually a structure containing an array).  It might be better to allow them to be cumulative with a separate `set_zero()` function to reset the structure (or you could use `memset()` — it would use it).